# HTML PHP array index lenght error

Tags: php, html

I have an html form where I am grouping inputs using name="array[]" then just looping through the array with PHP when submitted. Well I am using array[] to store the question, but when the question (array index) is longer than 64 characters then It will not pass that array key to my PHP.

HTML

```
<textarea name="corporate[CAN YOU SHOW US SIMILAR PROJECTS WITH THE SAME TARGET AUDIENCE? COMPETITORS?]"></textarea>
```

When I do:

```
var_dump($_POST['array']);
```

I get array(0)
But when I use a shorter index, it works.

Now if I manually create an associative array it works fine:

```
$array = array("CAN YOU SHOW US SIMILAR PROJECTS WITH THE SAME TARGET AUDIENCE? COMPETITORS?"=>"0");
```

What am I doing wrong?

I think it has to be a problem with going from the html form to the PHP. I am trying to loop through the inputs with my PHP so that I can loop through and display each question and corresponding answer with:

```
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if ($value != NULL) {
            echo '<strong>' . $key . '</strong><br/>';
            echo $value . '<br/><br/>';
        }
    }
```

Which gives me:

**Question**

Answer

**Question**

Answer

etc.

How else could I do this without giving each input their own name to pass the question, or hard coding the question in my HTML?

Comment: An idea could be to make a list of questions identified by id, then you submit these ids in your textarea name and then fetch the results from that.

Comment: Why you don't use name="corporate[]"?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I am trying to pass the question as the key.

Comment: in this case use a number

Comment: I don't want to reference the question with a number, I just want to pass the question

Comment: Could it be that the `?` isn't being urlencoded when you submit the form to your PHP script?

Comment: No, the ? works fine under 64 characters

Comment: If you insist on doing it this way, just because, you will have more problems that creep up.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you're doing this

```
var_dump($_POST['array']);
```

when you named the textarea "corporate". Try just doing

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input with the question and match up the indexes with the answer:

```
<input type="hidden" name="question[1]" value="CAN YOU SHOW US BLAH?">
<textarea name="answer[1]"></textarea>
```

I assume you are dynamically adding the question text?  If so you should probably use `htmlentities` on it to avoid issues.

Then just loop one and access the other:

```
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        echo '<strong>' . $_POST['question'][$key] . '</strong><br/>';
        echo $value . '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
```